# If $p^{r + 1} - 1 > 5(p^r - 1)$, then is there a lower bound for $p$ and $r$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, computational-mathematics, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

If $$p^{r + 1} - 1 > 5(p^r - 1),$$ then is there a lower bound for $p$ (e.g., in terms of $r$) and $r$ (e.g., in terms of $p$)?  Here, $p>1$ and $r \geq 1$.

I tried using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20p%5E(r%2B1)%20-%201%20%3E%205*(p%5Er%20-%201)%20for%20p), but I do not understand the resulting inequality plots.

[image: Solve p^(r+1) - 1 > 5*(p^r - 1) for p]

I also tried the **Reduce** built-in function in Mathematica (for which **InequalitySolve** is a precursor), but it returns the error message
*Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.*

Comment: It is likely impossible to solve for $p$ in terms of $r$ or vice versa, so that may also be a cause for this, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Here is the full graph of the inequality: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kaisu337qb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this does not actually answer the question on WolframAlpha but attempts to algebraically solve the inequality.  My only thought on that is that the shaded region is the solution set.  For example, the coordinate $(r,p)=(0,2)$ is in the shaded region, thus $2^1-1>5(2^0-1)$.

---

When $p^r>1,p>1$, we have

$$\frac{p^{r+1}-1}{p^r-1}=\frac{p^r+p^{r-1}+\dots+1}{p^{r-1}+\dots+1}=1+\frac{p^r}{p^{r-1}+\dots+1}>5$$

Thus,

$$p^r>4(p^{r-1}+\dots+1)>4p^{r-1}+4\int_0^{r-1}p^x\ dx=4p^{r-1}(1+\ln(p))-4>4p^{r-1}\ln(p)$$

Thus, we find that

$$p>4\ln(p)$$

$$p>8.613$$

These are some solutions that hold for any $r$ such that $p^r>1,p>1$ holds.

Without so much technical stuff, one could just note that when $p\ge5$, we have

$$p^{r+1}-1>p^{r+1}-5\ge5\times p^r-5=5(p^r-1)$$

Thus it holds for all $p\ge5$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed!  =)

Comment: Oh, okay.  :-) Glad to help then.

Comment: Hold on, is it not supposed to be the case that
$$\int_0^{r-1}p^x\ dx > p^{r-1} + \ldots + 1$$
and not the other way around?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I added in $p^{r-1}$ to the integral...

Comment: Your lower bound of $8.613$ does not corroborate the findings in the graph of the inequality.  Indeed, around $r = 1$, something a little less than $5$ appears to be the lower bound for $p$.

Comment: I think your integral should just be
$$\int_0^{r-2}p^x\ dx,$$
since you added out the $p^{r-1}$ outside of it.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I'm not sure what you mean.  It may be more intuitive if you tried graphing the integral.  And $p>8.613$ is perfectly fine as far as I can tell.  For all $r\in\mathbb R$ and $p>8.613$, we have $p^{r+1}-1>5(p^r-1)$.

Comment: Simply Beautiful Art, can you shoot me an e-mail via Google please?  (You can find my e-mail address in arXiv.)  Your proof here, if valid, resolves a wide-open conjecture on odd perfect numbers.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art